# Error installing protocol buffer on snow leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, python

I've just installed Google protocol buffer on my snow leopard mac. When going into the python shell

```
import protobuf
```

produces an unknown module error. I'm using the python which came with snow leopard:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Should I specify a PYTHON_PATH variable before installation and if so what should it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The module is not called `protobuf`, but `google.protobuf`. In the extracted [source tarball](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list), there's an `examples` directory. Run `make python` and check out the files `add_person.py`,`list_people.py` and `addressbook_pb2.py` to get you started. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That clarification really helped. Lesson learnt about following examples as well ;-)